# gdb remote debugging. Implement a fake gdbserver stub. After several requests and response, got a warning:invalid remote reply

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

For the needs of project, I wrote a simple java socket program to implement a "fake" gdbserver stub. Thus, support the minimum number of gdb RSP commands:g,G,m,M,c and s. For other commands, just response with "$#00". According to the manual of gdb, this would tell gdb that the "server" doesn't support other commands.

I use the Eclipse CDT to help me debug. In the debug configurations, I selected c/c++ remote application, and set the debugger connection using TCP on localhost:10000, where my java program will use to listen.

At first, gdb send commands like qSupported, Hg0, qTStatus, ?, and qC. The response to all of them are "$#00" to tell gdb the "server" doesn't support those commands. Then, gdb send qAttached and qOffsets. After sending two "$#00" responses and received a "+" from gdb, gdb says "warning: invalid remote reply:".

Can someone please tell me why did this occur? Why gdb doesn't send commands and say"invalid remote reply:", which I don't know what reply is invalid, after all, I just send "$#00" and "+" to gdb.

Comment: Not that I'll be able to help you, but it might make it more clear what is happening in your scenario if you showed a log of the actual conversation between GDB and your stub in a format similar to the examples used in the GDB docs: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Examples.html#Examples

Comment: I'm new to gdb and not sure how to generate that kind of conversation. But after I generate a "$S05#" response to "$?#", gdb seems work. It send "$g#" request and "$p8#" request. But now I get "PC register is not available" error after response to "$p8#" with "$#00"...

Comment: I too can't help you fully, but what I understood from the last sentence of this page: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Overview.html#Overview, is that a **minimal stub** must support commands: 'g', 'G', 'm' and 'M'. In case not the comm will fail. And you don't as per your last comment.

Comment: Should be OK to not support "P". To see remote protocol logging: "set debug remote 1". Presumably, since you are writing the server, you can make it write a log file with sent and received data.

Comment: Also, if you create a file ".gdbinit" in your home directory, you can put commands like "set  debug remote 1" and "set remotelogfile /tmp/remotelog.txt" into it - and it should get executed even when you start GDB from eclipse. I'd strongly suggest though that you run GDB from shell directly to start with - just to reduce the complexity - since Eclipse is going to be sending a bunch of GDB commands.

Answer (score 3):

This baffled me too when I read the GDB manual. I suspect that the set of commands you need to implement (i.e. those that should effect the state of your simulator) is a subset of the commands your server needs to be able to reply to.

This [excellent guide to writing an RSP server by Embecosm](http://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean4/embecosm-howto-rsp-server-ean4-issue-2.html) has a very handy sequence diagram in Section 3.1 which describes the initial handshake between GDB and your RSP server:

[image: Handshake sequence diagram]

Once you have the handshake working, it's much easier to see how the protocol fits together and start writing in the code that interacts with your simulator (or other target).